# Async Mutex in Microsoft CppRest SDK

Tags: c++, cpprest-sdk

I try to share some data between processes in my backend. How to protect them in async application without mutexes? I try to find something in documentation, but there is nothing in search on 'mutex' request.

I expect something like this:

```
http_listener listener(on_host);
listener.support([](http_request request) {
    GLOBAL_VAR.Async_Mutex.lock(); {
        GLOBAL_VAR.do_something();
    } GLOBAL_VAR.Async_Mutex.unlock();
    return request.reply(200);
});
listener
    .open()
    .wait();
```

Comment: Bit vague to understand where you are stuck. Why you expect CppREST to provide synchronization to your threads in processes? Both the C++11 locks and mutexes and winapi CreateMutex() stuff work but feel unrelated to REST api. Can you post simple code example how you have (or anticipate) data race from that CppREST?

Comment: @ÖöTiib , I know that I can't use std::mutex is this case, because it can deadlock async processes. I expect CppREST to provide blocking some resources, for creating some server global logic. (I add an expected code to question)

Comment: Unsure why it should deadlock. Is the do_something() supposed to throw between lock and unlock or attempt to lock again in same thread?

Comment: @ÖöTiib I think it should deadlock because async controller can give this thread to another async task in time then our task will do GLOBAL_VAR.do_something(), and thread will be locked and we never unlock it

Comment: Now I'm confused ... the CppREST lacks concept of async controller.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Sorry, I mean something that controls the execution of asynchronous tasks